# JQuery Mobile in Xpages, Passing Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, xpages

I am using the JQuery Mobile Framework in one of my Xpages applications.

I have made a listView with some entries and want to show the corresponding document when clicking on one of the entries. I have one XPage with two JQM Pages.

Do oyu have any idea how this could be possible in XPages? I know there are some plugins for JQuery mobile which add parameter functionality between pages, but my main problem is that there is no server-side event which is fired so that I could refresh my page and pass my documentID

Those are some things I tried before:

- Wrapping a div around my entry and tried to fire a serverside event -> No Event
- Using <'a> standard  element (which changes the page, but no parameter is given, for example via the url
- Tried to fire a XSP.partialRefreshGet when clicking the link, doesn't work because dojo has to be deactivated so that JQM can work properly
- Tried to fill a hidden Input for passing the parameter, useless, I need a serverside event
- Tried to open a new XPage when clicking on an entry to open the document, didn't work, either he can't find the xpage or I receive an error that XSP could not be found.
- Some more things I don't remember at this time

Does anyone have experience with using the JQM Framework in XPages? I can't imagine that there isn't a way i can get this to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used separate XPages for the view and for the document.

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Contacts</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
        <xp:repeat id="contactRepeat" rows="30" value="#{contactsView}" var="dataRow" disableOutputTag="true">
            <li>
                <xp:link escape="true" id="link1">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "m_ContactDetails.xsp?action=OpenDocument&documentId=" + dataRow.getDocument().getUniversalID();}]]></xp:this.value>
                    <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:return dataRow.getColumnValue("Name");}]]></xp:this.text>
                </xp:link>
            </li>
        </xp:repeat>
    </ul>
</div>
```

While I'm sure you could put both the view and the form on the same XPage (which is how I learned to do it in the extension library), I think having separate XPages works well and I know it allows me to pass the parameter.

In my extension library one, the link it opens to focus on the document part of the XPage and select a specific document is:

```
http://dominodev.mydomain.com/djn/Test.nsf/m_milestoneList.xsp#milestoneDetails&databaseName=DominoDev/MyDomain!!DJN\Test.nsf&documentId=5DDB32855213FC0485257B2D00730253&action=editDocument
```

So, I guess if you set the links from your dataview to use the #pageName and &documentId= it would probably work.....

Comment: Hmm, I already tried that. I tried it again, but it won't work. When click on the entry, I see the loading image but nothing else happens. I only receive an error message on the console of my browser, which says he couldn't find XSP, which is because Dojo is deactivated.
Did you see that before and maybe have an idea how I can fix it?

Comment: @MatthiasNicklisch, which one did you try - separate Xpages or using the hashtag to jump to the details page?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem, though it's a little bit strange. My colleague had to disable dojo because the UI wasn't rendered properly without switching it off.
I have activated dojo again in my page and link is now fully working without problems, which means I can open another XPage with the parameters I want.

Answer (score 0):

> My colleague had to disable dojo because the UI wasn't rendered
>   properly without switching it off

Yes, but I seems to be only a problem on ND 9 with dojo 1.8. 
The usal suspect just started to blog about this issue :) http://notesin9.com/index.php/2013/04/20/jquery-mobile-seems-incompatible-with-xpages-in-domino-9-0/

It works on 8.5.1 - 8.5.2 so far. Need to test on 8.5.3 but think, that it is only ND 9 / Dojo 1.8 related

I'v already tried with a different JQM namespace (data-bcc-role instead of data-role ) but the issue still exists. So IMHO it must be something different. 
Even noConflict() with jQuery did not help.

Answer (score 0):

According to a comment in http://notesin9.com/index.php/2013/04/20/jquery-mobile-seems-incompatible-with-xpages-in-domino-9-0/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+NotesIn9+%28Notes+In+9+-+Wordpress%29

> In jQuery Mobile version 1.3.1 in line 16 is the problem. I'm not sure
>   what the real problem is, but if you change line 13 to 23
>
> (function ( root, doc, factory ) { if ( typeof define === "function"
>   && define.amd ) { // AMD. Register as an anonymous module. define( [
>   "jquery" ], function ( $ ) { factory( $, root, doc ); return $.mobile;
>   }); } else { // Browser globals factory( root.jQuery, root, doc ); }
>
> to
>
> (function ( root, doc, factory ) {// Browser globals factory(
>   root.jQuery, root, doc ); }
>
> every thing will work

have tested and it works